# NSIS запуск приложения из другой директории

Tags: nsis

У меня есть установщик моего приложения и в него я хочу поместить MesageBox, который предложит установить драйвер, который находится в папке.

```
    MessageBox MB_YESNO "Do you have driver for your printer? Install now?" IDYES usbDriver IDNO ifNoAnsw
; driver USB
usbDriver:
ExecWait '$EXEDIR\PrinterDriver\DrvUty.exe' $0

ifNoAnsw:
DetailPrint 'You always can install driver in PrinterDriver directory'
```

Так вот, messageBox выскакивает, я кликаю "да" и запускается программа установки драйвера и выдает ошибку, что файлы драйверов не найдены. Тогда я поменял директорию с `$EXEDIR\PrinterDriver\DrvUty.exe` на `$EXEDIR\DrvUty.exe` и файл установщика своего приложения закиул в папку драйвера. Тогда все нормально заработало.

Так вот вопрос, как заставить это работать не меняя директорию и не перемещая мой файл.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было добавить `SetOutPath $EXEDIR\PrinterDriver`

```
MessageBox MB_YESNO "Do you have driver for your printer? Install now?" IDYES usbDriver IDNO ifNoAnsw
; driver USB
usbDriver:
SetOutPath $EXEDIR\PrinterDriver
ExecWait '$EXEDIR\PrinterDriver\DrvUty.exe' $0

ifNoAnsw:
DetailPrint 'You always can install driver in PrinterDriver directory'
```